# Is it possible to write files to an interactive shell within the declaration of a thread runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I'm attempting to start an interactive shell and then execute commands 
all with in a runnable thread.
I have not been able to even create a new file while in the runnable declaration.

## Example 1

```
if(true){
    Process p = null; 
    try{
        p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        BufferredWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new
        OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write("touch /data/local/tmp/file\n");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

## Example 2

```
public void createNewThread(){
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Process p = null;
            try{
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                BufferredWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new
                OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));                                                           
                writer.write("touch /data/local/tmp/somefile\n");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start(); 
}
```

In both Example 1 and Example 2 I see can see that have executed su and an interactive shell is running. 
However file is created in Example 1 but somefile is not created by Example 2. Is there some issue with writing to an interactive shell from with a runnable thread declaration?

Comment: note the low number of "followers" for many of your tags. AND you didn't include the most helpful tag, i.e. `[java]` ? Only programmers familiar with the language you're using will be able to help on a problem like this. Also note the definition attached to the [shell] tag, what you're asking is out of the realm of normal [shell] questions. Good luck.

Comment: I don't understand why you actually need a thread for all this. If your shell is interactive, how do you expect someone or something to interact with it ? I think something's wrong.

Comment: I would like to start the process from within a thread as a way to keep track of current threads that are running and therefore I'll know what process is running. My plan was to have a few different threads each with their own mutually exclusive process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, but maybe you need to explicitly `writer.flush()` ?

Also, you should always close you streams! This will have a bonus effect of automatically call `flush()`.

```
try {
    p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    BufferredWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    writer.write("touch /data/local/tmp/file\n");
} catch(Exception e) {
    // handle exceptions
} finally {
    writer.close(); // this will automatically call writer.flush()
}
```